# Revolution Slider Transitions Bug

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I have a Revolution Slider with just a single slide. Everything works perfectly except when I click somewhere on the slide and drag the mouse to the left or right. In that case I get a transition.

Any idea how to disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have two things to stop that. First you need to go to general settings -> stop slider (on) -> stop at slide 1

Second you need to disable mobile touch, go to mobile touch -> touch enabled off

On revolution slider 5 to disable mobile touch go to navigation -> touch -> touch enabled off

hope this helps